# What happens if I have to return something that I purchased with a credit card that is now canceled?

Tags: credit-card, fraud, shopping

I bought a few things on Amazon.com that I need to return.  However, the card I used was just canceled because of fraud/unauthorized use of the account (apparently a copy of it was made).

What will happen when I return the items?  Can Amazon credit a different card (any card)?  If not, can they credit the replacement card that I've already received?

Comment: From experience, you shouldn't worry about it at all. I had my card stolen and a previous refund went in to my new card without me intervening. I am in UK (it didn't happen with Amazon), not sure if it happens in other countries too.

Comment: The refund transaction actually references the original transaction, and it would be impossible to apply to a different card since that transaction did not occur on that card. However, the issuing bank will process the refund even if the transaction is on an old/expired/stolen card. Also, the old and new card belong to the same account with the issuing bank. They are only invalidating the old card not your entire account. This actually happens a lot, because merchants will often issue refunds on purchases made by thieves to avoid charge-backs.

Comment: @Jake refunds don't necessarily reference the original transaction. That may be true with the large scale retailers like Amazon or big boxes, but many mom-and-pop shops will just use a "negative" transaction - it will appear as a totally new transaction, just with a negative amount.

Comment: @littleadv Unreferenced credits are, in my opinion, rather irregular and a poor business practice, large or small. There is no way Amazon, which the question is about would do that. Any business that does this would lose the benefit of the original transaction being registered as refunded. In turn they wouldn't get their credit card fees refunded and the purchaser would still be able to file a charge-back.

Comment: @JakeBraun you're right about the fees, wrong about the chargeback. However, keeping the infrastructure to support this will cost much more than the fees savings for a small business with little refunds. As I said - for Amazon what you said is probably true, but as a rule - I wouldn't count on it for *any* transaction.

Comment: @littleadv I still disagree on charge-backs and cost. Given you are doing a new setup, small or large, the development costs are basically the same. It may even cost more in time to convince your processor you need the ability to do unreferenced credits. Without the transaction id on the refund, the bank has no way to know the charge-back should be disallowed immediately. The credit card associations (Visa, etc.) do not endorse this as a default method for refunds, this is really an implementation workaround. See: http://usa.visa.com/download/merchants/Public-VIOR-15-April-2014.pdf (page 458)

Comment: @littleadv I do agree technically speaking a business could do this, and so theoretically Amazon could as well. However, from a contractual and business policy prospective Amazon, and most other merchants, can not and will not do this. If a small business does do this as a regular practice, they are either skirting the rules of most card associations or misinformed about the correct method of issuing a refund.

Comment: @JakeBraun the charge backs may not be blocked by the processor, but it doesn't mean they will be accepted. The merchant will show the refund has been made and be done with that. For people who don't want to deal with complicated/expensive systems and don't take a lot of refunds/chargebacks - its an acceptable risk. As to the link - it says that the credit transaction should be identified on the receipt, but it doesn't have to be linked in the merchant's account.

Comment: @JakeBraun What rules are you talking about? I think you misunderstood the link you posted. You only need to provide the original transaction reference to the **customer**. Not the bank.

Comment: @litteadv I agree with you for some small legacy POS setups that the benefits may outweigh the risks. Still, they are likely not complying with the intent of the card associations rules. If they are doing an unreferenced credit for cost/time savings, I can't imagine they are manually appending the original info on the refund receipt. Also, the merchant gets charged for an unaccepted charge-back as well.

Comment: Some more rules from Visa on credits can be found in section "5.2.F.7 Credit Transaction" in the "Interlink Network, Inc. Operating Regulations", (page 136 in this PDF: http://usa.visa.com/download/merchants/interlink-operating-regulations.pdf)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Amazon* will **not** credit any different card. They cannot know that the different card number is in fact a replacement for the old one you used.

Your card issuer, however, can. If receive the refund form Amazon, and can transfer it to the new card. However, you need to talk to them and ask them if and how will they do that. They may decide to apply it to the fraudulent transactions' balance instead of giving it to you, to reduce their losses, so you need to talk to them beforehand and make sure that since the refund is for the purchase made *before* the card was cancelled, they will transfer it to the new card with all the rest of the information.

Another option is to request a refund to your Amazon account as a gift card balance for further purchases. I know that many retail shops will gladly give you a gift card instead of the cash/credit refund, so it may be worth your while to check with Amazon if they do that too.

Comment: Is there a legal reason why they won't credit a different card?  I just emailed Amazon to ask if I could somehow associate the new card number with that purchase.  I agree; I think they're unlikely to do this.  But if they wanted to, could they credit the new card?

Comment: @jer it opens up a whole new line of fraudulent behaviors, and since in this case they'd be giving out money - it is unlikely they'd want to subject themselves to such a liability.

Comment: Credit on old card would mean reversing the transaction. That merchant gets back the fees ... while credit on a new card would mean fees charged remain as they cannot be tracked to the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Well I bought something from a shop , my card was then stolen same as you and I took it back and just gave my new card from the same bank to them . Refund went through perfectly fine . That was interesting as I am unsure as to whether it was ok because it was the same bank or whether I could have just given any card . As they obviously didn't check the card. Perhaps the system isn't bothered as they are just putting through a refund , perhaps because it's down to the shop assistant to check . To prevent fraud . I'm going to try next time using another card next time I want a refund just out of curiosity . See what happens .